# images are not rendering in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have created a basic html and css page with images in it.
the page is working fine in chrome but image are not rendering in firefox
and have taken  image with svg format can u help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Hello, please, could you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your question is incomplete fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use SVG image can create restrictions on some browsers like Firefox, here are some examples :

- Javascript disabled
- External ressources cannot be loaded
- visited link aren't rendered

The onliest way to dodge these issues is to embed the SVG images with `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>`.

I think you should try to embed your image to see if they show again, else check if you're following the supported context to use SVG

You'll find further information on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image).